# Why is GraphiQL not auto completing/finding my interface fields?

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I am trying to use an `interface` in my `schema`.  Here is the `schema`:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Org",
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    paymentType: {
      type: PaymentType,
      resolveType: ({ isCreditCard }) => isCreditCard ? CreditCard : ACH
    }
});

export const PaymentType = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
  name: "PaymentType",
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    },
    name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    address: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(Address)
    }
  })
});

export const CreditCard = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "CreditCard",
  interfaces: [PaymentType],
  fields: () => ({
    number: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
  })
});

export const ACH = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "ACH",
  interfaces: [PaymentType],
  fields: () => ({
    routing: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    accountNumber: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
  })
});
```

When I go to my `GraphiQL`, I can see the `paymentType` and the fields that are in the `interface`, but I can't see the `CreditCard` or `ACH` information.  I must have something set up wrong?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the type(**CreditCard** or **ACH**) on a query for example ?

Comment: Is that normal that you're using both type and resolveType together on the export default ?